# shouldAutoRotateToInterface issues with setting up frames

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    float xCenter;
    float yCenter;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        NSLog(@"PORTRAIT ORIENTATION");
        xCenter = 384;
        yCenter = 512;
        self.username.center = CGPointMake(xCenter, yCenter-60);
        self.password.center = CGPointMake(xCenter, yCenter+10);
        self.login.center = CGPointMake(xCenter, yCenter+110);
        self.box.center = CGPointMake(xCenter, yCenter);
        self.info.center = CGPointMake(xCenter, yCenter+70);
        self.logo.center = CGPointMake(xCenter, yCenter-600);
    }
}
```

The NSLog prints correctly however it does not set all the center's. I have to change orientation to landscape and then back to portrait to have this into effect. Why is this? How do I make it to affect on the first load/app launch?

Comment: I think you need to use viewDidAppear... else just have a quick look into the UIViewController class reference for the method that fits your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is called prior to any rotations. It is called to verify which orientations are supported to see if it needs to rotate. You will have to use the methods listed [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW58).